# How to nearby hotels using google places api based on driving distance

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I know that I can search for hotels(for example) nearby a node by giving the radius of circle from the center node using google places api. But this returns places which are in other city. The reason is geographically the place is situated within the given radius. But the driving distance differs. Is there anyway to get around this?

Comment: Can you please provide an example to clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

The Places Search API will return places within a specified area ranked by prominence (popularity; "rankby=prominence"), or ranked by distance ("rankby=distance") independent of area.  There is no option to rank by driving distance.

To get a ranking based on driving distance, you may want to consider using the Places Search API in conjunction with the Distance Matrix API.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/

The Distance Matrix API will return driving, walking, or bicycling distances based on one or more origin locations, and one or more destination locations.